# Como alinhar um texto menor à parte superior do elemento pai?

Tags: css

Estou precisando deixar o ® do marca registrada menor e alinhada com a parte superior do texto, segue o *print* exemplo de como necessitaria

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Infelizmente graças aos outros fatores que estou utilizando neste elemento do site não consigo separar em 2, por exemplo 2 elementos de texto ou 2 div's.

```html
<h3 style="font-size:40px; font-color: #000;">
   <span>CVS<span style="font-size:24px;">®</span> - </span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como é um elemento `inline` vc pode usar `vertical-align: super` Ficaria como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo falo mais sobre top/superior

Segue código da imagem

```html
<h3 style="font-size:40px; font-color: #000;">
   <span>CVS<span style="font-size:24px; vertical-align: super">®</span> - </span>
</h3>
```

---

### Over Explain

Repare que todo texto cria uma "caixa de texto" onde o conteúdo fica dentro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa `caixa de texto` é defina pela `descender line` e `ascending line` e pode variar de `font-family` para `font-family`, pois ela é intrínseca ao arquivo da fonte (`.ttf` ou `.otf`).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Apesar disso não existe uma regra tipográfica, e nem da W3C, que diga que vc tem que alinha o `®` no `top` ou no `super`**

Veja como fica alinhando o `®` a `100%` do `vertical-align`, ele "cola" no topo da `caixa de texto`, e não no "topo do texto"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como entre duas famílias tipográficas vc pode ter uma "anatomia" diferente. Aqui temos a `Time New Roman` e a `Verdana`, as duas com o mesmo tamanho `20pt`, mas visualmente elas tem tamanho diferente, isso foi definido pelo designe da font e é algo referente ao arquivo em si...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem um artigo mais relacionado a tipografica, mas tem MUITA coisa interessante sobre a história da tipografia, e pq o **Figma** resolver mudar o seu entendimento do `line-height` e como ele é renderizado. https://www.figma.com/blog/line-height-changes/

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Segundo a Mozilla a tag `<sup>` não deve ser usada para isso, apesar de visualmente ficar parecido, não é uma tag feita para tratar *wordmark*.

> para estilizar a *wordmark* de uma empresa ou produto que usa uma linha de base elevada deve ser feito usando CSS (mais provável `vertical-align`) em vez de `<sup>`.

Uso apropriado da tag `<sup>`

- Expoentes tipo 3²
- Abreviações linguísticas como em francês "*mademoiselle*" = "M<sup>lle</sup>"
- Números ordinais como 4°

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup#Usage_notes

Comment: E talvez vale a pena citar que assim será utilizado a linha tipográfica que define a *ascender height*, não a *cap height*, o que justifica o símbolo ficar mais acima que as letras maiúsculas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss estou trabalhando nisso, achei algumas coisas interessantes

Comment: Tirei meu voto só para poder votar de novo +1

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss haha :D valeu jovem, aproveitei para incluir umas infos a mais. Esse lance da "caixa de texto" era algo que eu já tinha reparado. Até inclui um GIF a mais.

Comment: +1 pelos gifs :)

Comment: @DaviWesley haha, as vezes a gente tem que explicar "desenhando"... vlw 

Comment: caraca, essa foi a resposta mais completa que já vi. Parabéns demais!!! e valeu demais também!!

Comment: @GabrielRamalhoGrotto valeu pela força jovem! No inicio eu ate achei que seria uma resposta simples, mas reparei vários detalhes que aproveitei pra explicar de forma mais completa, []'s

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente usar a *tag* HTML `<sup>`

```html
<h3 style="font-size:40px; font-color: #000;">
   <span>CVS<sup style="font-size:24px">®</sup> - </span>
</h3>
```

Comment: Na verdade segundo a documentação da Mozilla o <sup> não é indicado para isso, *"to style the wordmark of a business or product which uses a raised baseline should be done using CSS (most likely vertical-align) rather than <sup>. "*, apesar de visualmente ficar com o aspecto similar ao que o autor precisa. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup

Comment: Aprendi um coisa nova.. eu já teria usado o `<sup>` mesmo...

Comment: @fernandosavio até editei minha resposta com mais algumas coisas interessantes que achei

Comment: Nenhum dos 2 deu certo, to fazendo um testes extras pra entender o porque. Caso queiram ver o resultado: http://comovendersoftware.com.br/ é logo de cara

Comment: E já ganhou meu +1...

Comment: Gabriel, provavelmente é erro no seu código.. A resposta do Hugo está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Sim, realmente está correto, no caso é a ferramenta que to utilizando pra esta empresa que está dando o problema, a resposta está corretíssima

Comment: enfim, só pro pessoal entender aqui: como estou usando wordpress, no código css geral estava falando que a tag sup era vertical-align: baseline;, só alterei para vertical-align: super; e funcionou

Comment: @GabrielRamalhoGrotto só que na resposta aqui ele nem fala de vertical-aling, ele usa a tag SUP, que por sinal não é recomendada!! Não etendi pq escolher essa resposta e não a outra, já que vc está usando vertica-align inclusive....

Comment: @Geremias ambos dão certos, caso estiver 0 de css no seu site o sup vai funcionar como o vertical super funciona

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usando FlexBox. Ve se te ajuda.

```html
<h3 style="font-size:40px; font-color: #000;">
  <span style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start">
            CVS<span style="font-size:24px;">®</span>
  </span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue esse efeito de alinhamento setando o `position` do elemento pai como `relative` e o `position` da tag `<span>` como `absolute` o alinhamento vai se dar ajustando as propriedades `top` e `font-size` desta tag.

```html
<h3 style="font-size:40px; font-color: #000; position:relative;">
   CVS<span style="position:absolute; top: 4px; font-size: 22px">®</span>
</h3>
```